# The smallest positive quadratic nonresidue a modulo m (composite)

Tags: residue-calculus, quadratic-residues

I need a metod to calculate **the smallest** positive quadratic nonresidue a modulo $m$. $m$ is composite.

I know chinese remainder theorem but it probably does not return always **the smallest** nonresidue?

I would be very grateful for your help.